# PopUp do something if the condition is met

Tags: java, android, popup, conditional-statements

So I made a custom dialog where it asks for information(like a feedback.
I want the app to check if all the EditTexts have value,
this is my java for opening feedback dialog

```
private void dialog() {
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_up);
    editTextEmailValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextMessageValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    editTextNumeValue = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextNume);
    Button btnSend = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    Button btnClose = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         //This is what I've tried (the check method is bewlow)
            if (check() > 1) {
                editTextNumeValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
                editTextMessageValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
                editTextEmailValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
            } else if (check() == 0) {
                sendMail();
            }
        }
    });
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    myDialog.show();
}
```

And this is my check method :

```
 private int check() {
    int counter = 0;
    if (editTextEmailValue.equals("")) {
        editTextEmailValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
        counter++;
    } else if (editTextMessageValue.equals("")) {
        counter++;
        editTextMessageValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
    } else if (editTextNumeValue.equals("")) {
        editTextNumeValue.setError("Obligatoriu!");
        counter++;
    }
    return (counter);
}
```

When I press the send button(for email) it enters the check method and goes out with 0 1 2 3 (I have only 3 textView) but when it checks in the `btnSend.onClickListener` if the condition are met it still send the mail so from that I can say from check method the counter have value 0 all the time so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic above is wrong. You are checking

```
if(counter > 1)
```

but your counter will never be greater than 1. Change it to
`if(counter > 0)` or `if(count >= 1)`

also use `editText.getText().toString()` for the correct editText entries !

and use `.isEmpty()` instead of `.equals("")`

Answer (score 0):

i agree with **Luis Fernando Scripcaru** .
and i suggest you one thing try **editTextEmailValue.getText().toString().equals("")** instead of **editTextEmailValue.equals("")**.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your check() method and try like this It might work :)

```
int Counter = 0;

btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     //This is what I've tried (the check method is bewlow)
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextEmailValue)){
    editTextEmailValue.setError("Error");
    Counter = 1;
    }
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextMessageValue)){
    editTextMessageValue.setError("Error");
    Counter = 2;
}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextNumeValue)){
    editTextNumeValue.setError("Error");
    Counter= 3;
}
if(Counter > 1){
   sendMail();
   //you can add other operations for 123 numbers too
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You check

```
if (check() > 1)
```

It will never be true. Because check() has IF ELSE, so only one increment will be performed and return value will never be more than 1, maximum value of our check is 1.

so, change this to

```
if (check() > 0)
```

or

```
if (check() >= 1)
```